# Error mounting, exit status 32, Can't mount my ext4 data partition

Tags: mount, ext4

I recently re-arranged my partitions and created a data partition so that I could access my files in both Windows and Linux Mint 18, without having to deal with NTFS.

All went well until yesterday when I shutdown Windows and booted up LM18 and was unable to mount the partition. Here is the error I get:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/abby/Storage: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda5" "/media/abby/Storage"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: mount /dev/sda5 on /media/abby/Storage failed: Bad message
```

I used `ext2fsd` to mount the `ext4` partition in Windows. I've done some searching, but can't seem to find much and honestly don't even know where to start. I'd like to avoid reformatting the partition as it has a ton of school documents and music on it that I'd rather not lose.

Answer (score 1):

First, is the disk still at `/dev/sda5`, or is this a stale `fstab` entry that needs updating due to a new device letter? Secondly, you've been using a rather odd file system driver within a non-posix OS. If you've been using it to write to your `ext4` file system, I would recommend running a full `fsck` on the volume.

I'd recommend doing that `fsck` even if it hasn't been obviously written to. Make sure the volume isn't mounted first. I don't think that will be a huge problem in this situation.